# ... for the reaction to, and prevention of, waste, loss and theft. (Commas correct?)

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is the comma correct after "to" and after "of" as shown below? Should a serial comma be inserted after "loss"? I cannot rephrase.

Herb is responsible for the reaction to, and prevention of, waste, loss and theft.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, they're _correct_, but replacing those two with dashes would reduce comma-clutter. I would personally then add the Oxford comma, as I usually pause before the final _and_ when reading, but that's up to you.

Comment: Like this, Ed? Herb is responsible for the reaction to -- and prevention of -- waste, loss and theft. I also think the spaced em dash provides greater clarity. Do you?

Comment: Those are not dashes. That being said, both parts of the question are duplicates.

Comment: You can make a dash with two consecutive hyphens. I am unable to make a regular dash on my smartphone.